# Reload page inside a php echo not working

Tags: php, javascript, html, echo

It seems as if I have tried everything. I read anything I could find on stack overflow and any other page, and nothing has yet functioned. The best I could do was for some reason an unlimited reload loop of the page in question that crashed my own internet connection.

```
echo '<td><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="kill(); ">Delete DB</a></td>';
```

My kill does the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">        </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function kill() 
{
$.get("killdb.php");
return false;
}
</script>
```

And I read through all this and tried all this: [Which "href" value should I use for JavaScript links, "#" or "javascript:void(0)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0) without any luck. Well maybe I did not do it all correct, but something is just not right. I cant get the page to reload for some mysterious reason.

Any takers?

Comment: where in your code are telling to javascript to reload the page?

Comment: The link and the `onclick` looks fine...as @martriay pointed out none of your example code contains anything that would even conceivably cause the page to reload.

Comment: I don't really know what you are trying to do, but it has nothing to do with the php echo. Although, what you are doing at the moment is that you are loading a php file, called killdb.php every time you click on the link. The file is loaded with Ajax. Is that what you are trying to do, or you want to go to that page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
function kill(){
    $.get('killdb.php', function(){ location.reload()});
}
```

So that the reload is not done before the ajax request is  completed

Comment: Works like a charm! You dear sir just solved a big headache for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the proper code to reload the page. Try this:

```
function kill() 
{
   $.get("killdb.php");
   location.reload();
   return false;
}
```

Comment: It now loads the page but does not execute the killdb.php